# Variable value being lost when looping through function

Tags: powershell

So I've got the following code that attempts to start a service (and validate connection to a server). If at any point the code fails it will rerun the whole segment in attempt to retry a set number of times before ultimately failing.

```
function retry_Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [scriptblock] $ScriptBlock,
        [int] $retryMax = 5,
        [int] $retryWait = 2,
        [string] $SuccessMessage = 'Executed successfuly.',
        [string] $FailureMessage = 'Failed to execute.'
    )
        
    process {
        $retryCount = 1
        $Flag = $True
        
        do {
            try {
                $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
                Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -OutVariable Result

                Write-Output "$SuccessMessage `n"
                $Flag = $False
            }
            catch {
                if ($retryCount -GT $retryMax) {
                    Write-Output "$FailureMessage Total retry attempts: $retryMax"
                    Write-Output "[Error Message] $($_.exception.message) `n"
                    $Flag = $False
                }
                else {
                    Write-Output "[$retryCount/$retryMax] $FailureMessage Retrying in $retryWait seconds..."
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds $retryWait
                    $retryCount = $retryCount + 1
                }
            }
        }
        While ($Flag)
    }
}

retry_Function {
    $CheckService = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
    $TCPObject = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

    if ($CheckService.Status -EQ 'running') {
        $Connect = $TCPObject.BeginConnect($centralAppDServer, $centralAppDPort, $null, $null)
        $Wait = $Connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, $False)
        if (-Not $Wait) {
            if ($isStarted -EQ $False) {
                Write-Output $isStarted
                Throw 'Error: service is running but could not listen on given port.'
            }
            else {
                Throw 'Error: service has been started but could not listen on given port.'
            }
        }
        else {
            $Error.Clear()
            $TCPObject.EndConnect($Connect) | Out-Null
            if ($Error[0]) {
                Write-Warning ('{0}' -f $Error[0].Exception.Message)
            }
            else {
                Write-Output 'Success: service is already running and listening on given port.'
            }      
        }
    }
    else {
        Start-Service -Name $serviceName
        $CheckService = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
    
        if ($CheckService.Status -EQ 'running') {
            $Connect = $TCPObject.BeginConnect($centralAppDServer, $centralAppDPort, $null, $null)
            $Wait = $Connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, $False)
            if (-Not $Wait) {
                $isStarted = $True
            }
            else {
                $Error.Clear()
                $TCPObject.EndConnect($Connect) | Out-Null
                if ($Error[0]) {
                    Write-Warning ('{0}' -f $Error[0].Exception.Message)
                }
                else {
                    Write-Output 'Success: service has been started and is listening on given port.'
                }      
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Output 'Error: service could not be started.'
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, if for example the service was not started (and was subsequently started) then the value for `$isStarted` will be set to `True` once and then the moment the code loops it's set back to `False`. Is there an elegant way to solve this problem? Or rather, is there a way for me to get the value of `$isStarted` to persist between loops?

Comment: It seems to me that your code could be simplified to remove the duplication - e.g. (pseudocode) ```retry_Function { if (service is *not* started) { start service; throw if failed to start }; BeginConnect; WaitOne; if( $wait ) { ... } else {...} }``` and the whole ```$isStarted``` flag becomes unnecessary  - the code starts the service if needed, but in either case it still checks the TCP connection. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @mclayton, I'm not sure I follow.. ideally I'd like to be able to retry both steps (starting the service and testing the connection). If either step fails, they should be reattempted. Could you elaborate? (Sorry for the trouble)

Comment: I'll try... so it looks like you've got two steps: (i) ```if (the service is not started) then { start the service}``` and (ii) ```test the tcp connection```. These are independent steps, although (i) has to be performed before (ii), but what you're doing is combining the steps: ```if( the service is started ) then { test the TCP connection } otherwise { start the service and test the TCP connection}```, and duplicating the code for ```test the TCP connection``` in both parts of the ```if``` - you can move that code out *after* the ```if``` instead and just have it there once. Does that help?

Comment: @mclayton I think so! You've got me thinking.. you reckon I could just wrap the two independent steps in between the ```retry_function``` separately? So first, attempt to start the service, then based on that attempt to test the TCP connection?